# Spring data jpa relationship of shared entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have an entity Address,
if entity Person and entity Institution would have same address, which relationship should I use between these entities?
two one-to-one or one-to-many?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
Person -> Address <- Institution
```

So the mapping is a `@ManyToOne` from `Person` to `Address` and a `@ManyToOne` from Insitution to `Address`.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    // all other fields

    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Institution {
    // all other fields

    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I would say you will not need a relationship from `Address` to `Person` and `Institution`.

Comment: You mean I don't have to annotate address in Person and Institution? Without relation, does Address variable in these entities persist?

Comment: I updated my answer with the mapping that you have to do in the class Person and Institution.

Comment: Thank you, would you explain a bit when should I add relation in both entities and when should not?

Comment: That depends on the use case. In that particular case having a collection of people and institutions in the address class probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: Suppose Entity A has a list of Entity B, once I delete an entity B, I want the entity A remain persistent but B in the list is automatically deleted, which relation should I use?